# Bundle Docker image as an executable application for major platforms / Can we run docker images without docker?

Tags: windows, macos, docker, cross-platform, executable

I would like to build an application as an executable that anyone could start without any requirements and without GUI.

Do you know if we can bundle a Docker image as an executable app for Mac OS or Windows (and Android/iOS) ?

Another way to phrase it, can we run docker images without docker installed ? can we bundle a docker image and docker inside an app and when executed it starts a docker container with the embedded docker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is just a set of linux features ([windows containers](https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/definition/Microsoft-Windows-Containers) use similar windows features), so as long as you pack what ever you need to set everything just like docker (or any other container runtime like podman) does for you it will probably work. Just notice if using a docker image you'd need to unpack its files and do everything the docker engine and CLI are doing for you.

It depends on the application type but you could use a [PWA](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/) which runs as a native desktop application on computers and smartphones and has similar functionality while using general purpose [web frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_framework) like [React](https://reactjs.org/), Angular or Vue.

If you want to run an executable regardless of the operating system or architechture docker's your best bet, and if being light weight and daemonless is your thing consider using [podman](https://podman.io/) as your application dependency and running your application
with it or its likes